# How do I configure a Scala case class in Spring?

Tags: spring, scala

I have a case class like this:

`case class ElasticIndex(name: String, host: String, port: Int)`

… and I need to configure an instance of it using Spring. The actual configuration data is supposed to come from a properties file. Looking at the Java code, it seems something like this would be ideal:

`case class ElasticIndex(@Value("${es.name}") name: String, …`

… but looking at the documentation, I don't think that's going to fly.

What are you supposed to do in cases like these?

(I don't feel like turning my `ElasticIndex` class into a JavaBean. Making your code mutable just for sake of supporting the framework just doesn't seem right.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate `@Configuration` class that has a `@Bean` method with `@Value` parameters.

I prefer specifying properties in`@Configuration` classes, since it makes the code more reusable: you can create another setup by loading another configuration class.